# Why is my .env.local not recognized by docker-compose for the container_name attribute?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, environment-variables

In my starter docker project i have a `.env` file which is strangely loaded automatically. But now I wanted to rename the `.env` to `.env.local`. I also added in my `docker-compose.yml` the attribute `env_file: .env.local`. But I am since then not able to set the variable for the `container_name` attribute (`container_name: ${APP_NAME}-wordpress`).

**Question 1:** Is docker-compose even capable of loading a file other than .env?

**Question 2:** Is it default behavior that docker compose loads the .env by default without specifying the env_file attribute?

```yaml
version: '3'

services: 

  wordpress:
    image: wordpress:latest
    env_file: 
      - "./docker.config/.env"
    container_name: ${APP_NAME}-wordpress # THIS LINE MAKES TROUBLE!
    depends_on:
      - wpdb
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./wp_data:/var/www/html/
    ports:
      - "88:80"
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: ${MYSQL_USER}
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: wpdb:3306

  wpdb:
    image: mariadb:latest
    env_file: 
      - "./docker.config/.env"
    container_name: ${APP_NAME}-database # AND THIS LINE MAKES TROUBLE!
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes: 
      - ./db_data:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}
      MYSQL_DATABASE: ${MYSQL_DATABASE}
      MYSQL_USER: ${MYSQL_USER}
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}

volumes:
  wp_data:
  db_data:
```

If i check with `docker-compose config` then i will see that all vars are loaded but docker-compose is not able to set the container_name. That is the reason for my error message: `Error response from daemon: Error when allocating new name: Invalid container name (/-database), only [a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9_.-] are allowed`

**Output docker-compose config**

```
  wpdb:
    container_name: -database
    environment:
      APP_NAME: MY-APP
```

Comment: Can you remove the double quotes around the path: `- ./docker.config/.env.local`

Comment: @WLefever Is it advisable not to use the quotes?

Comment: How do you validate that it doesn't work? Please make the problem reproducible.

Comment: All your questions are answered here: https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/set-environment-variables/ Yes, `.env` is loaded by default.

Comment: @DanielW. Thank you. It is helfpful link. Now I found that the problem is the container_name attribute. I updated my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question 1: Yes, Docker Compose is capable of loading environment variables from a file other than .env. When you use the env_file attribute in your docker-compose.yml, you specify the path to the environment file from which Docker Compose should load the environment variables. In your case, you've set env_file: .env.local, which should make Docker Compose load environment variables from the .env.local file in the same directory as your docker-compose.yml file.

Question 2: Yes, Docker Compose does have a default behavior of loading environment variables from a .env file in the same directory as the docker-compose.yml file. If you don't specify the env_file attribute in your docker-compose.yml, Docker Compose will automatically look for a .env file and load the environment variables from there. This is part of the convenience that Docker Compose offers to manage environment variables for your services.

Comment: Thank you POONAM for your answer. It is helpful. Unfortunately, I realized that I did everything right. The problem is that I want to set the container_name attribute as well. I have already updated my question. Maybe you have an idea how to do that?